# Error checking with Aeson

Tags: json, haskell, aeson

This code parses a recursive JSON structure into a haskell object that I made. I'm using the Aeson library. The problem that I'm encountering is that I want to be able to do error checking easily, even with a recursive call. Right now I use a dummy value (ayyLmao) whenever an error occurs. However I would like to leverage the error checking I get from the Parser monad. How can I do this and possibly clean up my code in the process? If necessary I can also post some sample JSON.

EDIT: I'd like to point out that I'd like to get rid of "ayyLmao" (hence the stupid name), and somehow use 'mzero' for the Parser monad for my error checking instead.

```
type Comments = Vector Comment

data Comment = Comment
    { author :: Text
    , body :: Text
    , replies :: Comments
    } deriving Show

-- empty placeholder value (only should appear when errors occur)
ayyLmao :: Comment
ayyLmao = Comment "Ayy" "Lmao" V.empty

parseComment :: Object -> Maybe Comments
parseComment obj = flip parseMaybe obj $ \listing -> do
    -- go through intermediate objects
    comments <- listing .: "data" >>= (.: "children")
    -- parse every comment in an array
    return $ flip fmap comments $ \commentData -> case commentData of
        -- if the data in the array is an object, parse the comment
        -- (using a dummy value on error)
        Object v -> fromMaybe ayyLmao (parseMaybe parseComment' v)
        -- use a dummy value for errors (we should only get objects in
        -- the array
        _ -> ayyLmao
        where
            parseComment' :: Object -> Parser Comment
            parseComment' v = do
                -- get all data from the object
                comment <- v .: "data"
                authorField <- comment .: "author"
                bodyField <- comment .: "body"
                replyObjs <- comment .: "replies"
                return $ case replyObjs of
                    -- if there are more objects, then parse recursively
                    Object more -> case parseComment more of
                        -- errors use the dummy value again
                        Just childReplies -> Comment authorField bodyField childReplies
                        Nothing -> ayyLmao
                    -- otherwise, we've reached the last comment in the
                    -- tree
                    _ -> Comment authorField bodyField V.empty
```

EDIT: The code in the answer below is correct, but I'd like to add my modified solution. The solution given assumes that "null" indicates no more replies, but for some reason the API designers decided that that should be represented by the empty string.

```
instance FromJSON Comment where
    parseJSON = withObject "Comment" $ \obj -> do
        dat <- obj .: "data"
        commReplies <- dat .: "replies"
        Comment
            <$> dat .: "author"
            <*> dat .: "body"
            <*> case commReplies of
                Object _  -> getComments <$> dat .: "replies"
                String "" -> return V.empty
                _         -> fail "Expected more comments or a the empty string"
```

Comment: Using a placeholder value isn't very idiomatic Haskell, have you considered returning a `Maybe Comments` value to represent the concept of failure and then at the point where you might get `Nothing` using `Data.Maybe.fromMaybe (ayyLmao)` instead?  Or you can use the fact that the Aeson parser has a concept for failure and use it in much the same fashion.

Comment: @bheklilr Yeah using a placeholder value isn't very idiomatic anything, that's why I gave it such a stupid name. Using Maybe would work, but I'd much rather just use the error checking that Aeson already has (mzero for Parser will be interpretted as an error). However, I don't quite know how to get the types to line up the way I want them. Any tips for doing it that way?

Comment: Well, usually the parse type uses `mzero` to represent failure.  Have you seen tutorials like [this one](https://www.fpcomplete.com/school/starting-with-haskell/libraries-and-frameworks/text-manipulation/json)?

Comment: Yes I know that. From my reply: "mzero for Parser will be interpretted as an error". I'm wondering how I can do it in this case. I'm working over a Vector of comments, so I basically would have to recognize an error in the middle of an fmap and somehow return mzero for the whole thing. Or I could have a list of Parsers and then fold it into one larger parser (would that even work?). Not exactly sure what would be the best thing to do there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You hit the mark with "Or I could have a list of Parsers and then fold it into one larger parser". This is exactly how you would propagate errors from nested parsers. The minimum change to your code to remove `ayyLmao` would be:

```
parseComment :: Object -> Maybe Comments
parseComment obj = flip parseMaybe obj $ \listing -> do
    -- go through intermediate objects
    comments <- listing .: "data" >>= (.: "children")
    -- parse every comment in an array
    V.sequence $ flip fmap comments $ \commentData -> case commentData of
        -- if the data in the array is an object, parse the comment
        -- (using a dummy value on error)
        Object v -> parseComment' v
        -- use a dummy value for errors (we should only get objects in
        -- the array
        _ -> mzero
        where
            parseComment' :: Object -> Parser Comment
            parseComment' v = do
                -- get all data from the object
                comment <- v .: "data"
                authorField <- comment .: "author"
                bodyField <- comment .: "body"
                replyObjs <- comment .: "replies"
                case replyObjs of
                    -- if there are more objects, then parse recursively
                    Object more -> case parseComment more of
                        -- errors use the dummy value again
                        Just childReplies -> return $ Comment authorField bodyField childReplies
                        Nothing -> mzero
                    -- otherwise, we've reached the last comment in the
                    -- tree
                    _ -> return $ Comment authorField bodyField V.empty
```

This uses `mzero` for the error cases and propagates errors from the list of replies with `V.sequence`. `sequence` is a exactly the thing that takes a list of parsers (or, in this case, a vector) and folds into a single parser that either succeeds or fails.

However, the above is not a very good way to use aeson. It's usually better to derive an instance of the `FromJSON` type-class and work from there. I would implement the above as

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import qualified Data.Vector as V
import Data.Vector (Vector)
import Data.Text (Text)
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)

import Control.Applicative

type Comments = Vector Comment

data Comment = Comment
    { author :: Text
    , body :: Text
    , replies :: Comments
    } deriving Show

newtype CommentList = CommentList { getComments :: Comments }

instance FromJSON Comment where
    parseJSON = withObject "Comment" $ \obj -> do
        dat <- obj .: "data"
        Comment
            <$> dat .: "author"
            <*> dat .: "body"
            <*> (fromMaybe V.empty . fmap getComments <$> dat .: "replies")

instance FromJSON CommentList where
    parseJSON = withObject "CommentList" $ \obj -> do
        dat <- obj .: "data"
        CommentList <$> dat .: "children"
```

This introduces a wrapper type `CommentList` which is used to fetch the `obj.data.children` attribute from the JSON. This takes advantages of the existing `FromJSON` instance for `Vector` so you don't have to manually loop through the replies and parse them separately.

The expression

```
fromMaybe V.empty . fmap getComments <$> dat .: "replies"
```

assumes that the `replies` attribute in the JSON contains either a `null` value or a valid `CommentList` so it tries to parse a `Maybe CommentList` value (`null` is parsed to `Nothing`) and then replaces a `Nothing` value with an empty vector using `fromMaybe`.

Comment: Wow thanks so much! I hadn't heard of sequence until now, that's super useful. I was also thinking about using a FromJSON instance. I started out doing that, but didn't really understand what all the types did so I started doing everything manually. I think this really helped me learn a whole bunch.

Also I would love it if the replies attribute contained null when there were no more replies (or perhaps an empty list). But the API designers thought it would be a good idea for the empty string to mean "no more comments".